# How to update a label control every nTH seconds on winform?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a label on my winform that when the form loads, counts how many files are in a directory. I want to update that label every nTH seconds while the winform application is running. I'm not sure how to acheive this, here's my on load to count the files:

```
Public Function getUserCountsTotal() As Integer
    Dim di As New DirectoryInfo("C:\myDirectory")
    Dim Users As FileInfo() = di.GetFiles().OrderByDescending(Function(fi) fi.LastWriteTime).ToArray()

    Dim user As FileInfo

    'list the names of all files in the specified directory
    For Each user In Users
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(user.Name) & "- " & user.LastWriteTime)
    Next

    getUserCountsTotal = ComboBox1.Items.Count + 1
End Function

    Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
    statusPanel.Text = ""
    statusPanel.Text = "Logged in as " & getYourUserName() & " - " & "[ " & getUserCountsTotal() & " ]  "
End Sub
```

Comment: Use a [Timer?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: The number keeps adding up because you keep adding new items to the `ComboBox` without removing the old ones. You need to call [**`ComboBox.Items.Clear()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.objectcollection.clear(v=vs.110).aspx) before you start adding new items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a timer on a form and set the `Enabled` property to **true**. Double-click on the timer and enter the code that counts the files in the directory:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim counter = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles("C:\myDirectory")
    Label1.Text = counter.Count
End Sub
```

You set the interval in Timer's `Interval` property in milliseconds. To update every two seconds set the value to 2000, to update every three seconds set it to 3000 etc.